# How to test the test cases in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing the test case of controller function and i want to **test the test case** which i write the test case that is correct or not how i test the already written test case ???

> Below the test case

```
describe "#show_bid" do
 render_views

 before do
   bid =  FactoryGirl.create(:bid)
   get :show_bid, :id => bid.id, :user_email => @user.email, :user_token => @user.authentication_token, :format => :json
 end
 it "should pass params to show_bid" do
   #binding.pry
   expect(assigns(:params)[:id]).not_to be_nil
 end
 it "Request should be get type and their route should be match" do
   #binding.pry
   expect(assigns(:params)[:action]).to eq("show_bid")
   #get "bid_detail"
 end
 it "response should be 200" do
   assert_response :success
 end
```

end

Comment: Try this: `bundle exec rake test`

Comment: But i am test the test case how to check which  test case i write that is correct or not ?? Can i test specific controller functions test cases ???

Comment: You can mention the file name at the end `bundle exec rake test test/integration/file_to_test.rb`

Comment: This command is used to run the test_case which i already used with r ***rspec* but i want to check the test_case which is written that is correct or not ???

Answer (score 0):

Test the test case?

Theoretically you can create a new test B for your test case A. And then create a test C for test B. And again and again.. But you can do it endlessly, and no one does it like this.

On the other hand you can use **TDD** *(test-driven development)* methodology. It has five steps:

1. create a new test
2. run all tests and check that the new test does not pass (*it's like test for your test!*)
3. write the code
4. run all tests again and ensure that all tests pass
5. do refactoring

By the way, I see that there are only clean tests in your test case. They can only validate that the contoller method works correctly. You can try to create dirty tests which aiming at breaking the site. For example, it can be a test case without user data.